# How to split view multiple buffers in vim

Tags: buffers, split

Working with big projects, I often find myself needing to view/edit several files at once.

If I have multiple buffers open, is there a way to split the window to view multiple files in one command?

E.g. usually I begin my workflow by entering my project's root directory, entering `vim` in the terminal, and then entering `:n **/*.py` to recursively load all python files that exist in the project as buffers.

Simple example, I have these buffers:

```
:ls
  1 %a   ".vimrc"                       line 1
  2      "rsync_to_home.bash"           line 0
  3      "README.md"                    line 0
  4      ".zshrc"                       line 0
```

I want to split the screen to show `"rsync_to_home.bash"`, `".zshrc"`, along with the current buffer (`.vimrc`), as horizontally split windows. To accomplish this, I would have to do:

```
:sb 2 <Enter>
:sb 4 <Enter>
```

But calling :sb for each file individually is tedious, and `:sb 2 4` doesn't work. Also, if I'm working with a lot of files, I would probably have to repeat `:ls` between the `:sb` calls to make sure I'm calling the right buffer numbers.

Comment: You can also pass `:sb` a buffer name... For example `:sb rsy` followed by `:sb zsh`, with any unique substring of the buffer (file) name. Regarding using a single command, how about joining them with `|`? `:sb rsy|sb zsh` should work...

Comment: Joining the calls works, I'll go with that or I'll create a function and add to .vimrc if that's the only way

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could write a wrapper to do all the commands at once:

```
command -bar -nargs=+ -complete=buffer Sbuffers execute map([<f-args>], {_, b -> printf("sbuffer %s", b)})->join("|")
```

Usage: `Sbuffers file1 file2 file3`

Completion will use buffer names (so the buffers have to have been loaded). You can tweak this to use any file names with `-complete=file`, though according to `:help :sbuffer` files loaded from outside the buffer list will not have `'buflisted'` set.

The general idea is to build up the string `sbuffer b` for each buffer `b`, and then join them with `|` to be one command:

```
sbuffer b1|sbuffer b2|sbuffer b3
```

And then `:execute` the whole lot.

We can do this by mapping over the list of arguments (`[<f-args>]`—`<f-args>` turns the arguments into a list suitable for a function call, which happens to the be same form as needed to make a literal list with `[]`). The one subtlety is that lambdas/Funcrefs given to `map` are given both the index/key *and* the value, hence the `_` wildcard in the lambda arguments.

Answer (score 4):

As filbranden pointed out, it is possible by joining the `sb` calls like e.g. this:

`:sb rsy|sb zsh`

This is useful for when first loading a large project. E.g. by going to project root directory, entering `vim` in terminal, calling `:n **/*.py` to load all python files recursively under the current directory (project root), then calling `:ls` to view all loaded files in buffer, and then to view multiple individual files on one window you use `:sb file1.py|sb file2.py|sb file3.py ...`

Answer (score 1):

Just adding on to [d-ben-knoble](https://vi.stackexchange.com/users/10604/d-ben-knoble)'s answer (stackexchange won't let me comment on it yet), I mapped:

- <leader>v (Vertical splits)
- <leader>z (horiZontal splits)

I'm sure others will need to use other letters for the mapping.

```
command -bar -nargs=+ -complete=buffer Sbuffers execute map([<f-args>], {_, b -> printf("sbuffer %s", b)})->join("|")
nnoremap <leader>z :ls<cr>:Sbuffers<space>
command -bar -nargs=+ -complete=buffer Vbuffers execute map([<f-args>], {_, b -> printf("vsplit \#%s", b)})->join("|")
nnoremap <leader>v :ls<cr>:Vbuffers<space>
```

So, to get 4 vertically split windows with buffers 1-4, if your leader key is default `\`, you can type straight from normal mode:

```
\v 2 3 4
```

Note: Vim 8.0.1763 (and earlier?) don't like the post command: `->join`, so

```
command -bar -nargs=+ -complete=buffer Sbuffers execute join(map([<f-args>], {_, b -> printf("sbuffer %s", b)}), "|")
nnoremap <leader>z :ls<cr>:Sbuffers<space>
command -bar -nargs=+ -complete=buffer Vbuffers execute join(map([<f-args>], {_, b -> printf("vsplit \#%s", b)}), "|")
nnoremap <leader>v :ls<cr>:Vbuffers<space>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you know you want to open the files in multiple windows you can call vim with the following flags:

```
   -o[N]        Open N windows (default: one for each file)
   -O[N]        Like -o but split vertically
```

in your example:

```
vim -o **/*.py
```

would load all the files into their own window.

Comment: Note: this may not open a separate window for all the files, if there is not enough room (e.g. you are trying to open too many files at once)