# How to split view all buffers in vim with equal distribution vertical horizontal

Tags: vimscript, buffers, macro, split, plugin

How can I split view all buffers in vim with a distribution between vertical and horizontal?  Is there a plugin?

I know how to make all buffers appear in either horizontal or vertical splits:

```
:ball
:vertical ball
```

But I want several to be vertical first, then, once a reasonable number have displayed, start creating a 2nd row below it: so a horizontal split.  Then, continue the process so we end with tiled windows.  Maybe if there are 7 buffers:

```
|| x | x | x ||
|| x | x | x ||
||     x     ||
```

**Use Case**

Let's say I want to use bufdo on all my buffers.  I'd like to see the changes they are making as much as feasible.  Even on a small screen, I could make 4 vertical splits above 4 horizontal ones, and see a little bit of each file.  More than 9 buffers, and it's probably too small to read, so maybe there could be a vimrc-changeable setting for user preference of max number of splits, and/or perhaps some influence based on screen resolution or display width ability.

**Beginning of an answer**

Based on the [answer here](https://vi.stackexchange.com/a/37342/41830), I'm tempted start macro'ing that, and I can see that temptation turning into writing my first plugin.  I just feel like surely this is a common enough desire to already have an existing plugin or solution.

Comment: The question is not clear to me- what kind of layout are you trying to achieve?  What do you man by "equal distribution vertical horizontal?"

Comment: Updated question for clarity.  Apologies, I'm still not sure if it's clear, lmk.

Comment: Interesting question. You might be able to "watch" the changes if you disable `lazyredraw`; otherwise I recommend investigating them with another tool, like `git diff` or `:help DiffOrig`